# Ionic styling container

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

Can some help format my ionic code in order to look like picture 1?[image: Picture1]

picture 2 is how it currently looks[image: picture2]

here is the code:

```
<ion-content  >
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row class="ion-text-center">
      <ion-col size="0.9" *ngFor="let c of images; let i = index">
        <img src="../assets/cards/cardBackground/cardBackground.png" *ngIf="!c.isFlipped" (click)="selectCard(c)"/>
        <img [src]="imageDir + c.name +  '.png'" *ngIf="c.isFlipped && !c.isMatched"  (click)="selectCard(c)"/>
      </ion-col>
      
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row class="ion-text-center" >
      <ion-col >
        <ion-card  class="card-class">
          <img  src="../assets/playIcons/player1.svg"/>
          <ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-title>{{this.player1["name"]}}</ion-card-title>
            <ion-card-title>Score: {{this.player1["score"]}}</ion-card-title>
          </ion-card-header>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>

      <ion-col >
        <ion-card class="card-class">
          <img src="../assets/playIcons/player2.svg"/>

          <ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-title>{{this.player2["name"]}}</ion-card-title>
            <ion-card-title>Score: {{this.player2["score"]}}</ion-card-title>
          </ion-card-header>
        </ion-card>

      </ion-col>

     
    </ion-row>
  
  </ion-grid>

</ion-content>
```

Im not experienced in frontend as much and would really appreciate help thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to have a nested grid. eg

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center ion-justify-content-center">
        <ion-col size="3">
             <ion-card  class="card-class">
                <img  src="../assets/playIcons/player1.svg"/>
                <ion-card-header>
                <ion-card-title>{{this.player1["name"]}}</ion-card-title>
                <ion-card-title>Score: {{this.player1["score"]}}</ion-card-title>
           </ion-card-header>
         </ion-card>
       </ion-col>
       <ion-col size="6">
           <ion-grid>
               <ion-row class="ion-text-center">
                   <ion-col size="0.9" *ngFor="let c of images; let i = index">
                       <img src="../assets/cards/cardBackground/cardBackground.png" *ngIf="!c.isFlipped" (click)="selectCard(c)"/>
                       <img [src]="imageDir + c.name +  '.png'" *ngIf="c.isFlipped && !c.isMatched"  (click)="selectCard(c)"/>
                   </ion-col>
               </ion-row>
           </ion-grid>
       </ion-col>
       <ion-col size="3">
           <ion-card class="card-class">
               <img src="../assets/playIcons/player2.svg"/>

               <ion-card-header>
                   <ion-card-title>{{this.player2["name"]}}</ion-card-title>
                   <ion-card-title>Score: {{this.player2["score"]}}</ion-card-title>
               </ion-card-header>
            </ion-card>
       </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

You may want to look at breaking down the nested grid's cards into separate rows.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have learnt something now and it looks so much better